# Do change over from Xcode 6.3 to Xcode 7.0 cause some error?

Tags: xcode, swift

Hi I developed a photo sharing app just like Instagram in `Xcode 6.3`.I was using swift programming. While using few of its code in another project that was created in `Xcode7.0` I find some error in it.Why this happens? Can someone help me?

**Edit**

```
@IBAction func dashboardClick(sender: UIButton){

        let FaceLoginViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("dashboardoptions")as UIViewController

        self.presentViewController(FaceLoginViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
```

I get this error message:

> Downcast from 'UIViewController?' to 'UIViewController?' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'?

Comment: which bugs you are facing? Please explain(Sharing a code snippet will be a plus).

Comment: I am getting a error like Downcast from UIViewController @pkc456

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32974755/988169 Similar goes for UIViewControllers

Comment: Please see my edit @pkc456

Comment: Exacty WHAT error do you get?

Comment: Never use capitalized variable names.

Comment: I have a doubt whether there will be problem when building a app in ipad that is developed using Xcode 6.3 ? @Arbitur

Comment: @Anu In xcode 6.3 Swift 1.2 was used, in xcode 7 Swift 2 is used. They changed stuff. Give us the error message, please

Comment: Swift Compiler error:
 Downcast from 'UIViewController?' to 'UIViewController?' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'?@Arbitur

Comment: Just remove `as UIViewController` in ios9 it returns a UIViewController by default instead of AnyObject like it did pre ios9.

Comment: Make this as seperate answer please @Arbitur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before ios9 `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` returned `AnyObject`, now it returns `UIViewController` so no need to cast.

remove the cast and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

This is because Swift2 is not backward compatible with Swift 1.2/

Comment: Thank you. Please tell me  what is  the solution for this? @Alexander Chernenko